# Capture image continuously using ARCore Camera without AR objects?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arcore, android-camerax

The reason I don't want the Augmented 3D objects to be present in the image, is because I'm sending the image for object detection. The augmented object would just come in the way.

I have tried using [Camerax](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) API. The setAnalyzer function just stops analyzing when the ARFragment is loaded (I guess because it overrides its camera)

Is there any way where I can capture image without 3D models being present. That screen capture function should be in my `ArFragment`.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Have you made any progress?